# Menelaus' Theorem and Power of a Point

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

> A circle is tangent to side BC of $\triangle ABC$ at its midpoint $M$, and intersects sides $AB$ and $AC$ at points $E,F$, and $G, H$. Prove that $\displaystyle\frac{BP}{CP} \cdot \frac{BQ}{CQ}=1$.
>
> [image]

My attempt:

I used Menelaus' Theorem in $\triangle ABC$ with transversals $P-F-G$ and $Q-H-E$.

$\displaystyle\frac{AF}{BF} \cdot \frac{BP}{CP} \cdot \frac{CG}{AG} = 1$ and $\displaystyle\frac{AE}{BE} \cdot \frac{BQ}{CQ} \cdot \frac{CH}{AH} = 1$.

When these two are multiplied together:

$\displaystyle\frac{AF}{BF} \cdot \frac{BP}{CP} \cdot \frac{CG}{AG} \cdot \frac{AE}{BE} \cdot \frac{BQ}{CQ} \cdot \frac{CH}{AH} =1$.

Then using power of a point:

In the numerator $\rightarrow$ $AF$ and $AE$ cancel out with $AG$ and $AH$, $CG$ and $CH$ cancel out with $BF$ and $BE$ thus leaving us with $\displaystyle\frac{BP}{CP} \cdot \frac{BQ}{CQ} =1$.

Is my attempt correct? Does the fact that $M$ is the midpoint have to be used somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel out $CG\cdot CH$ and $BF \cdot BE$ only because: $$CG\cdot CH = CM^2 = BM^2 = BF\cdot BE$$
So the use of $M$ is here (otherwise you can't cancel them out).

Note: The power of point $C$ is given by $CG\cdot CH = CM^2$ and the power of point $B$ is given by $BF\cdot BE=BM^2$, so they are equal if and only if $BM=CM$.

Comment: And for point A: $AE \cdot AF$ cancels with $AG \cdot AH$ ?

Comment: Yes :) for point $A$ that is correct.